# What command would let me know Which connection links are participating VLAN 2 spanning tree?

Tags: cisco, switch, network

Which connection links are participating VLAN 2 spanning tree?

Comment: With MSTP or with RPVST+ ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the global `show vlan` command to show the VLANs and on which interface(s) each VLAN is active.

Answer (score 1):

For what kind/model switch?

On most Cisco switches the command would be 'show spanning-tree vlan 2' or just 'show spanning-tree' for more broad information. There are tons of other commands that might be of interest and they might be different depending on the model/brand of switch.